# How to code a cooldown timer for multiple users?

Tags: c#

I'm coding an IRC bot with C#. I have a bunch of commands set up such as !uptime and !help. I don't want people spamming the commands because I could get banned for spamming. The trigger happens when you send 20 messages in 30 seconds.

I have coded mirc bot before and in mirc you can set up individual timers for each user to prevent them from using it more than once in 30 seconds. I also had to make a global flood variable that ties all the commands to not send more than 20 messages in 30 seconds.

Could someone please show me how to do what I did in mirc in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a really basic method of this would be to keep a list of users who have executed requests with your bot and check from their last time they made a request. its very basic, but for a simple IRC bot it should do just fine.

```
    List<User> Users = new List<User>(); // list of all users

    public bool IncomingRequest(string RequestingUser)//requesting user == username of the person messaging your bot
    {
        User TempUser = Users.FirstOrDefault(User => User.Username == RequestingUser);
        if (TempUser != null)// check to see if you have handled a request in the past from this user.
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - TempUser.LastRequest).TotalSeconds >= 30) // checks if more than 30 seconds have passed between the last requests send by the user
            {
                Users.Find(User => User.Username == RequestingUser).LastRequest = DateTime.Now; // update their last request time to now.
                return true;
            }
            else // if less than 30 seconds has passed return false.
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else // if no user is found, create a new user, and add it to the list
        {
            User NewUser = new User();
            NewUser.Username = RequestingUser;
            NewUser.LastRequest = DateTime.Now;
            Users.Add(NewUser);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

user class

```
class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastRequest { get; set; }
}
```

you can easily add a counter that adds up how many requests have happened in the last 30 simply by iterating an int whenever that functions returns true and having a check for

```
if (counter >20 && (Datetime.now - LastCounterReset).TotalSeconds >= 30)
{
    // reset counter and LastCounterReset 
} 
else
{
    // reject request
}
```